# Can't Hit Drupal Module with PHP Storm Debugging

Tags: php, debugging, drupal, xdebug, phpstorm

Im trying to hit a module from Drupal with PHP Storm and xdebug.  I can hit the index.php file, but not this module.  Any clue?

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
```

When I try to validate remote environment from the debug/servers section I get "Failed to execute validation script".

Comment: Just to get the dumb questions out of the way: you're sure the line you are debugging is reachable - like if you put a drupal_set_message('hi'); or a die(); there it does?
Also have you tried different breakpoints in the module? I sometimes spend a while scratching my head before I notice I put it on a line like '$somevalue = array(' which it won't let me break on and drupal has a lot of.

Comment: Put `xdebug_break();` in your code to manually invoke breakpoint from your code. If PhpStorm will not catch it up (considering that xdebug and IDE is properly configured already and can debug in general), then possibly the file is outside the project dues to symbolic links or something (remember: xdebug works with resolved/real paths ONLY while IDE uses what it was given).

Comment: Another most obvious notice: xdebug v2.2.0 is not really stable (don't know if those issues apply to you or not) -- minimal recommended version of 2.2 branch is 2.2.1 -- consider upgrading your xdebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happened but today it started working.  I believe I had the wrong module file open, which was from the website.  PHP Storm adds external libraries that contain the same code, but if I update one it wont update the other file.  So I updated the external library file with breakpoints and confirmed it's working.